# ¿Cómo importar una clase de Java?

Tags: java, clase, java-import

Tengo un problema para importar una clase de Java. Resulta que tengo los siguientes directorios:

```
/desktop/MorganLab/model/Cliente.java
/desktop/MorganLab/model/GeneralDate.java
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo sería la sintaxis para importar dentro de la clase Cliente, la clase GeneralDate ? Estoy ejecutando desde el terminal)

Tengo esto, pero no funciona:

Clase Cliente:

package model;
   import model.GeneralDate;

Clase GeneralDate:

package model;

Comment: Como ambas clases están en el mismo paquete no tienes que agregar el import para poder usarlas

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente declara propiedades de tipo `GeneralDate` en la clase `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente {

    private GeneralDate fecha_nacimiento; //Propiedad fecha_nacimiento de tipo GeneralDate

}
```

Al convivir en un mismo package, podrán verse entre ellas mientras sean `public/protected`.